# Jenkins pipeline parallel stage with slightly difference

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline job that will trigger a group of nodes do some similar things.

The code is something like below.

```
#!groovy
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      parallel {
        stage('Server01') {
          agent {
            label 'Server01'
          }
          steps {
            sh 'do-something-01 --name Server01'
            sh 'do-something-02 --name Server01'
            sh 'do-something-03 --name Server01'
            sh 'do-something-04 --name Server01'
          }
        }
        stage('Server02') {
          agent {
            label 'Server02'
          }
          steps {
            sh 'do-something-01 --name Server02'
            sh 'do-something-02 --name Server02'
            sh 'do-something-03 --name Server02'
            sh 'do-something-04 --name Server02'
          }
        }
        stage('Server03') {
          agent {
            label 'Server03'
          }
          steps {
            sh 'do-something-01 --name Server03'
            sh 'do-something-02 --name Server03'
            sh 'do-something-03 --name Server03'
            sh 'do-something-04 --name Server03'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to follow DRY code principle.

Can I wrap the specific step into a function and use parameters to change the function behaviors? I'm not familiar with groovy

Something like below

```
#!groovy
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      parallel {
        stage('Server01') {
          agent {
            label 'Server01'
          }
          steps {
            // function is defined in somewhere
            function('Server01')
          }
        }
        stage('Server02') {
          agent {
            label 'Server02'
          }
          steps {
            function('Server02')
          }
        }
        stage('Server03') {
          agent {
            label 'Server03'
          }
          steps {
            function('Server03')
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to keep declarative pipeline then you need to add `function('Server01')` as a var and use it as a library. Please refer this [Extending Shared Libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/).

In case you are ready to switch from declarative to a scripted pipeline, then you get the flexibility of defining functions in the Jenkinsfile.

Below is an example Scripted pipeline

```
stage ('Build') {
  function('Server01')
}

def function(serverName) {
  node {
      sh 'do-something --name serverName'
  }
}
```